# Why the factor $1/2$ in quadratic penalty function?

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

The quadratic penalty function is commonly written as follows

$$\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}\mu \sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2 = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}\mu c^\top c$$

One could just as easily drop this factor and use $\mu' = \frac 1 2\mu$, so I'm assuming there is a reason why it's included, but what? Is it just a matter of style to halve quadratic terms?

Comment: Because it cancels out with you differentiate, avoiding to copy the embarrassing $2$ over and over.

Comment: since $$x^2'=2x$$, mutiply factor 1/2 to get  $$0.5x^2'=x$$, a more convenient result in both vision and application